# why NULL in a json after JSON.stringify?

Tags: php, jquery, json

php 5.4 fastcgi
jquery 1.10

Jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "",
          dataType: "json",
          data: { json: JSON.stringify({test: 'teste'}) }
        }).done(function(msg) {
              var msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
              alert(msg);
        });
```

PHP code:

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
$info = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($info);
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  ["test"]=>
  string(5) "teste"
}
null
```

i dont know why this **null** apper and how to remove it. Because if i try to use:

```
$i = info['test'];
echo $i;
```

i will recieve:
**testenull**

Comment: No need to `stringify`, you're already setting `dataType:'json'`

Comment: dataType:'json' is for what you expect to recieve from server. The problem is not the response to jquery, the problem is the null value inside json.

Comment: Try just `data: {test: 'teste}` then access in PHP like `$test = $_POST['test']`. jQuery will serialize your data.

Comment: are you sure the "null" is not coming from another place? it appears outside the array in `var_dump($info)`

Comment: @koala_dev , thanks, yes, the null came from another thing, problen solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your **JSON** data is the issue.

**`json_decode()`** in **PHP** takes a JSON encoded string as input and converts it to a PHP variable.

It works like this

```
<?php
$json = '{"test": 12345}';
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'test'}; // 12345
?>
```